# The term 'Get-OrElse' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

**The term 'Get-OrElse' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
| path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

[image]

Powershell is installed in my system . The version that is installed is 5.1.19041.1645 .  Please help me how can I fix this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Your question, as it stands, is unclear. Please provide some more code or better information on what you're trying to accomplish.

`get-orelse` isn't a valid powershell command afaik. you might be looking for [this function](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSDataKit/1.0.0/Content/functions%5CGet-OrElse.ps1) in the gallery.

Comment: I am using the command like : Get-OrElse -Value $DataAccess.DataApi.Replicas -Default 2

Comment: How can I refer this in my project so that project uses it automatically .

Comment: Functions are about avoiding duplicate code which can be done on several levels here. Functions in PowerShell need to be declared before they are executed, so I tend to put all my functions at the top of my script.

Answer (score 1):

As I state in my comment - I believe you are trying to call a function in a script. You must either declare the entire function or it's path before you can call it.

```
Write-Host "Before calling Function."

## all my functions go here
function Get-OrElse {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        [Object]$Value,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [Object]$Default
    )
    if ($null -eq $Value) {
        return $Default
    }
    switch ($Value.GetType().Name) {
        "String" {
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Value)) {
                return $Default
            }
            else {
                return $Value
            }
        }
        "Hashtable" {
            if ($Value.count -eq 0) {
                return $Default
            }
            else {
                return $Value
            }
        }
        "Object[]" {
            if ($Value.count -eq 0) {
                return $Default
            }
            else {
                return $Value
            }
        }
        Default {
            return $Value
        }
    }
}

##now i can call my delcared function
Get-OrElse
```